# ¿Por que se enciman los elementos en QScrollArea en qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo este código para mostrar imágenes, hice una lista de `qlabel` para mostrar las imágenes y otra  mostrar los nombres, las agrego a un `QGridlayout` para mostrarlo en un `QScrollArea`

```
QFileInfoList lst_img;
lst_img = QDir(Files_img).entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllEntries);

QScroller::grabGesture( ui->scrollArea_2 , QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
ui->scrollArea_2->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {height:0px;}");
int num_img=lst_img.count();
if(num_img==0)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Carpeta vacia"," No hay ninguna imagen disponible" );
}
else
{

_Direc.setPath(Files_img);

gridLay_img= new QGridLayout( );

int x=0,y=0;//contadores para espacios de gridlay

for(int k=0;k<lst_img.count();k++)
{
   
    click_labelimg *etiqueta = new click_labelimg();
    label_most_img<< etiqueta;

    name_img=lst_img.at(k).baseName();
    read_img.setFileName(lst_img.at(k).absoluteFilePath());
    read_img.setScaledSize(QSize(100,60));
    lbl_img = new click_labelimg;
    label_most_img.at(k)->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(read_img.read()));
    label_most_img.at(k)->setScaledContents(true);
    label_most_img.at(k)->setFixedSize(100,60);
    lbl_name_img << new QLabel(this);
    lbl_name_img.at(k)->setText(lst_img.at(k).baseName());
   

    gridLay_img->addWidget( label_most_img.at(k), y, x );
    y++;

    gridLay_img->addWidget(lbl_name_img.at(k),y,x);
    x++;
    y--;
    gridLay_img->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20,30),y,x);
    x++;
   
}

ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents_2->setLayout( gridLay_img );
ui->Ventanas->setCurrentIndex(3);
}
read_img.setFileName("");
}
```

y este método para borrar todo y poder mostrar distintas imágenes, es el método de un botón que cambia el `index de stackedwidget`, y borra las listas usada

```
     void MainWindow::on_btn_atras_galimg_clicked()
{



delete gridLay_img;

while(!lbl_name_img.isEmpty())
    delete lbl_name_img.takeFirst();
while (!label_most_img.isEmpty())
    delete label_most_img.takeFirst();
label_most_img.clear();
_btnSignalMapper_img->removeMappings(this);


ui->Ventanas->setCurrentIndex(1);
}
```

el problema aparece cuando intento mostrar las mismas imágenes dos o mas veces, se enciman los elementos Así aparecen la primera vez: [image: imagenes mostradas por primera vez]

Así aparecen cuando intento mostrarlas por segunda vez: [image: imagenes mostradas por segunda vez]

Comment: Si te fijas, las barras de scroll no están saliendo en ningún momento. Dado que tienes widgets personalizados yo apostaría a que se encuentra ahí el origen del problema. Puedes probar a llamar a `setFixedSize` en los `clicklabel_img` a ver si de esa forma obligas al QScrollArea a mostrar las barras de scroll

Comment: use esto ui->scrollArea_2->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {height:0px;}"); para quitar la barra de scroll, ya lo elimine y si fue eso lo que me estaba dando problemas, la situación es que necesito que desaparezca

Comment: si no quieres barras de scroll el widget no te va a dejar hacer scroll. Para hacer lo que pretendes vas a tener que  crearte un widget y programarlo a mano